# How to install Datastax DevCenter without Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, ubuntu-16.04

I have downloaded and installed Cassandra according to this guide: http://cassandra.apache.org/download/

Now I'd like to install Datastax DevCenter, but the problem is that I cannot find a standalone Datastax DevCenter download and / or instructions how to download and install only the Datastax DevCenter without installing and setting up yet another Cassandra node.

DeveCenter installation guide: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/devcenter/doc/devcenter/dcInstallation.html

According to the video the install will setup Cassandra node and optionally install DevCenter and other tools.

It is also said that the APT package installer does not install DevCenter:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html

I have Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I found the link where to download all datastax tools:

https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/ops-center?destination=downloads/ops-center&dxt=DXcom